# Library management using a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Hey I was trying to simulate a simple Library management system using Shell Script as part of my college UNIX assignment but I'm having a weird errors in script.

Here is my script

```
menu_choice=""
record_file="bookRecords.ldb"
temp_file=/tmp/ldb.$$
trap 'rm -f $temp_file' EXIT


get_return(){
printf '\tPress return\n'
read x
return 0
}
 
get_confirm(){
printf '\tAre you sure?\n'
while true
do
  read x
  case "$x" in
      y|yes|Y|Yes|YES) 
      return 0;;
      n|no|N|No|NO)
          printf '\ncancelled\n'
          return 1;;
      *) printf 'Please enter yes or no';;
  esac
done
}

set_menu_choice(){
clear
printf 'Options:-'
printf '\n'
printf '\ta) Add new Books records\n'
printf '\tb) Find Books\n'
printf '\tc) Edit Books\n'
printf '\td) Remove Books\n'
printf '\te) View Books\n'
printf '\tf) Quit\n'
printf 'Please enter the choice then press return\n'
read menu_choice
return
}

insert_record(){
echo $* >>$record_file
return
}
 
 
#!!!!!!!!!...........................!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
#This function ask user for details information about book for keeping records
 
add_books(){
 
#prompt for information
 
printf 'Enter Books category:-'
read tmp
liCatNum=${tmp%%,*}
 
printf 'Enter Books title:-'
read tmp
liTitleNum=${tmp%%,*}
 
printf 'Enter Auther Name:-'
read tmp
liAutherNum=${tmp%%,*}
 
#Check that they want to enter the information
printf 'About to add new entry\n'
printf "$liCatNum\t$liTitleNum\t$liAutherNum\n"
 
#If confirmed then append it to the record file
if get_confirm; then
   insert_record $liCatNum,$liTitleNum,$liAutherNum
fi
 
return
}

find_books(){
grep computer $record_file > $temp_file
    
  set $(wc -l $temp_file)
  linesfound=$1
 
  case "$linesfound" in
  0)    echo "Sorry, nothing found"
        get_return
        return 0
        ;;
  *)    echo "Found the following"
        cat $temp_file
        get_return
        return 0
  esac
return
}


$temp_file
 
 set $(wc -l $temp_file)
   linesfound=$1
 
   case "$linesfound" in
   0)    echo "Sorry, nothing found\n"
         get_return
         return 0
         ;;
   *)    echo "Found the following\n"
         cat $temp_file ;;
        esac
 printf "Type the books titel which you want to delete\n"
 read searchstr
 
  if [ "$searchstr" = "" ]; then
      return 0
   fi
 grep -v "$searchstr" $record_file > $temp_file
 mv $temp_file $record_file
 printf "Book has been removed\n"
 get_return
return
}
 
view_books(){
printf "List of books are\n"
 
cat $record_file
get_return
return
}



edit_books(){
 
printf "list of books are\n"
cat $record_file
printf "Type the tile of book you want to edit\n"
read searchstr
  if [ "$searchstr" = "" ]; then
     return 0
  fi
  grep -v "$searchstr" $record_file > $temp_file
  mv $temp_file $record_file
printf "Enter the new record"
add_books
 
}

rm -f $temp_file
if [!-f $record_file];then
touch $record_file
fi
 
clear
printf '\n\n\n'
printf 'Mini library Management'
sleep 1
 
quit="n"
while [ "$quit" != "y" ];
do
 
#funtion call for choice
set_menu_choice
case "$menu_choice" in
a) add_books;;
b) find_books;;
c) edit_books;;
d) remove_books;;
e) view_books;;
f) quit=y;;
*) printf "Sorry, choice not recognized";;
esac
done
# Tidy up and leave
 
rm -f $temp_file
echo "Finished"
 
exit 0
```

error while executing:

```
manage.sh: line 12:  : command not found
manage.sh: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
manage.sh: line 19: `      y|yes|Y|Yes|YES) '
```

And any further suggestions to improve the script will be well appreciated.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You have `$temp_file` followed by `set $(wc -l $temp_file)`.  You need to create the file, otherwise `wc` returns an error.  Did you mean `> $temp_file`?

Comment: kudos for having a big chuck of code completed for your assignment. There are numerous things to comment on, but I'll pick just one topic (`return`). A. Unix/Linux philosophy/std-coding-practices says `return 1` (or other non-zero) to indicate error condition. You are returning `0` everywhere. B. having `return` as the last line of a function (without returning a variable value), will always return `0` and is redundant (unneeded) as the function will return `0` by default (without any code). Less code is almost always better. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

sounds to me like you're using some other shell than `bash`. line 12 is the end of a function definition to `bash`, but not e.g. to `csh`, which there gives `}: Command not found.` similarly, `bash`'s `case` syntax is `bash`-specific, and e.g. `csh` errors on line 19 with: `Too many )'s.` these aren't the exact errors you're getting, so you're not using `csh`, but you're probably not using `bash` either. try invoking your program with:

```
bash manage.sh
```

or, better, do:

```
`which bash`
```

then put the result of that on the first line of your script after a `#!`, e.g.,

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
```

depending on where `bash` is located on your system.

then do this once:

```
chmod +x manage.sh
```

and invoke your script like this thenceforth:

```
./manage.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

The script has some explicit issues,

- Add the below lines next to temp_file=/tmp/ldb.$$ to create an empty file and grant necessary permission.

  ```
  touch $temp_file ;
  chmod 644 $temp_file
  ```
- Just next to the function definition of remove_books(), you are trying the execute $temp_file which I guess you are NOT intending to do. remove the line '$temp_file'
- Seems you missed the starting block for the function find_books().
- You are trying to find the number of lines in ldb file by executing the below lines

  ```
  set $(wc -l $temp_file)
  linesfound=$1
  ```

  whcih doesn't seem to be correct. Instead you could achieve executing the below line,

  ```
  linesfound=`cat $temp_file|wc -l`
  ```

Here is the modified script with quick fixes,

```
menu_choice=""
record_file="bookRecords.ldb"
temp_file=/tmp/ldb.$$
touch $temp_file; chmod 644 $temp_file
trap 'rm -f $temp_file' EXIT


get_return(){
printf '\tPress return\n'
read x
return 0
}

get_confirm(){
printf '\tAre you sure?\n'
while true
do
  read x
  case "$x" in
      y|yes|Y|Yes|YES)
      return 0;;
      n|no|N|No|NO)
          printf '\ncancelled\n'
          return 1;;
      *) printf 'Please enter yes or no';;
  esac
done
}

set_menu_choice(){
clear
printf 'Options:-'
printf '\n'
printf '\ta) Add new Books records\n'
printf '\tb) Find Books\n'
printf '\tc) Edit Books\n'
printf '\td) Remove Books\n'
printf '\te) View Books\n'
printf '\tf) Quit\n'
printf 'Please enter the choice then press return\n'
read menu_choice
return
}

insert_record(){
echo $* >>$record_file
return
}


#!!!!!!!!!...........................!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
#This function ask user for details information about book for keeping records

add_books(){

#prompt for information

printf 'Enter Books category:-'
read tmp
liCatNum=${tmp%%,*}

printf 'Enter Books title:-'
read tmp
liTitleNum=${tmp%%,*}

printf 'Enter Auther Name:-'
read tmp
liAutherNum=${tmp%%,*}

#Check that they want to enter the information
printf 'About to add new entry\n'
printf "$liCatNum\t$liTitleNum\t$liAutherNum\n"

#If confirmed then append it to the record file
if get_confirm; then
   insert_record $liCatNum,$liTitleNum,$liAutherNum
fi

return
}

find_books(){
  echo "Enter book title to find:"
  read book2find
  grep $book2find $record_file > $temp_file

  # set $(wc -l $temp_file)
  # linesfound=$1
  linesfound=`cat $temp_file|wc -l`

  case `echo $linesfound` in
  0)    echo "Sorry, nothing found"
        get_return
        return 0
        ;;
  *)    echo "Found the following"
        cat $temp_file
        get_return
        return 0
  esac
return
}

remove_books() {
# $temp_file

  #set $(wc -l $temp_file)
  #linesfound=$1
  linesfound=`cat $record_file|wc -l`

   case `echo $linesfound` in
   0)    echo "Sorry, nothing found\n"
         get_return
         return 0
         ;;
   *)    echo "Found the following\n"
         cat $record_file ;;
        esac
 printf "Type the books titel which you want to delete\n"
 read searchstr

  if [ "$searchstr" = "" ]; then
      return 0
   fi
 grep -v "$searchstr" $record_file > $temp_file
 mv $temp_file $record_file
 printf "Book has been removed\n"
 get_return
return
}

view_books(){
printf "List of books are\n"

cat $record_file
get_return
return
}



edit_books(){

printf "list of books are\n"
cat $record_file
printf "Type the tile of book you want to edit\n"
read searchstr
  if [ "$searchstr" = "" ]; then
     return 0
  fi
  grep -v "$searchstr" $record_file > $temp_file
  mv $temp_file $record_file
printf "Enter the new record"
add_books

}

rm -f $temp_file
if [!-f $record_file];then
touch $record_file
fi

clear
printf '\n\n\n'
printf 'Mini library Management'
sleep 1

quit="n"
while [ "$quit" != "y" ];
do

#funtion call for choice
set_menu_choice
case "$menu_choice" in
a) add_books;;
b) find_books;;
c) edit_books;;
d) remove_books;;
e) view_books;;
f) quit=y;;
*) printf "Sorry, choice not recognized";;
esac
done
# Tidy up and leave

rm -f $temp_file
echo "Finished"

exit 0
```